# Stop videoview when click another videoview on a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-videoview, recycle

I have a listview and it has custom adapter. Adapter keeps videoview items on it. On list, when I click a videoview it is starting to play that is working ok. But after when I click next videoview, the previous one continue to playing. Here is my question: how can I stop previous videoview, when I clicked next one ? 
Thanks.

Custom Adapter Codes:

```
public class Node_Content_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter<Node_Content_Item>  {

Context context;
int ResourceId;
public Node_Content_Adapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
        List<Node_Content_Item> objects) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, objects);
    this.ResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Node_Content_Item itemObj = getItem(position);
    View listItemView;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflator = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if(convertView==null)
        listItemView = layoutInflator.inflate(ResourceId, null);
    else
        listItemView=convertView;
    final RelativeLayout rlayout=(RelativeLayout) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.rlayout);  
    final VideoView video=(VideoView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.videoViewMain);
    //There is a layout over videoview and when layout clicked video starting to play
    rlayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(video.isPlaying())
            {
                video.stopPlayback();
            }
            else
            {
                Uri uri=Uri.parse(itemObj.getVideourl());
                video.setVideoURI(uri);
                video.start();
            }
        }
    });
    return listItemView;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Is there any error in your LogCat?

Comment: @Skizo when I clicked a videoview how can I stop other videoviews on recyling structer ?